# What steps to take in painting this damaged wall?

Tags: repair, walls, painting, primer

[image]

Water leak from above windows created bubbles.  I stripped the damaged section with putty knife, did I go too far? What steps should I take next? I'm new at this, I think I'm supposed to add primer and then a coat of paint.

Comment: Ed's answer below and the Onetime(r) product will work. The big thing is the leak is no longer present that created the problem to begin with.

Comment: I just don't understand why normal primer (sealer) is not preferred in this situation since the whole wall was done this way? Still solving the leak problem.

Comment: Yes, regular primer will work, please be certain the leak is gone and the wall is absolutely dry.

Answer (score 2):

Did you go too far? I don't think you did. It is best to remove the loose material. I would use some topping compound and fill the area and lightly sand. This will give a normal look. If you just prime and paint it will be visible for years. I use topping mud where I need a thin coat. It sands easier then prime and repaint and you will have a professional looking repair.

Comment: Never heard of topping mud before, what's it usually used for so I can know what to ask for? Btw this is not drywall.

Comment: Yes it looks like plaster, I would still use topping mud it is a softer lighter form of drywall mud. It is easier to put a thin coat down and easier to sand, anyplace that sells sheetrock / mud will have topping mud many places will have small tubs like a quart for a few $.

Comment: I can find it if only I have a description people will understand since I'm in a non English country.

Comment: This store here has the most products but don't know where it is: http://www.cmbegypt.com/cmbgroup/products/admixtures/

Answer (score 2):

Here is the over kill but guaranteed way to fix this. There are steps you can skip, but the paint may crack/peel/bubble/not stick if you do. Water damaged gypsum board can be tricky.

Remove any loose material. Lightly sand. Apply [Zinsser Gardz](https://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/zinsser/primer-sealers/gardz-problem-surface-sealer/). Allow to dry and lightly sand. Patch/skim with spackle/mud. Allow to dry and lightly sand. Repeat application of spackle/mud and light sanding if necessary to achieve acceptable finish level. Apply Zinsser Gardz. Allow to dry and lightly sand. Finish with 2 coats of normal paint.

Comment: It can be hard to find the product or equivalent since I'm not based in US.  but is this the same thing which I got? https://www.reddevil.com/index.php?l=product_detail&p=912

Comment: No, that's not the same thing. Look for a primer that will either repair damaged wallboard, fix peeling paint, allow painting after removing wallpaper, or prevents bubbles after skim coating. If I were you, I would buy Gardz on eBay from anyone who will ship internationally.

Comment: I forgot to say my wall isn't drywall.